# BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is the wrong type 'objectId', expected type 'object'

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to delete duplicates from a very large collection so I can add an index.

This is the query I am running:

```js
var cur = db.Profiles.aggregate(
    [
        { $group: { _id: { value: "$website_url" }, uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
        { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } }
    ],
        { "allowDiskUse" : true })
    
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    var index = 1;
    while (index < doc.uniqueIds.length) {
        db.Profiles.deleteOne(doc.uniqueIds[index]);
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```

The query fails with this error:

> BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is the wrong type 'objectId', expected type 'object'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[deleteOne is expecting a filter document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#std-label-deleteOne-filter) but you are passing an objectId.

Instead you should pass a filter specifying which document you want to delete. In your code, it would be the document with an `_id` equal to the objectId `doc.uniqueIds[index]`: `{ _id: doc.uniqueIds[index] }`

Your code would then look like this:

```
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cur.next();
    var index = 1;
    while (index < doc.uniqueIds.length) {
        db.Profiles.deleteOne({ _id: doc.uniqueIds[index] }); // Filter document passed here
        index = index + 1;
    }
}
```